# Is this a valid use of css3 :not()

Tags: css

This is somehow not working: `#ipadmenu.oldcontent ~ :not(#ipadmenu.newcontent) ~ #content.newcontent article {width:728px}`

Is this normal? If this is correct it might be because of some other css rule that is conflicting, but I cannot seem to find it.

Did I do something wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: Firebug has a nice "applied CSS rules" view. I'm sure there are other tools (for other browsers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s a syntax error, as you can check with http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ (though its report is a bit cryptic in this case). The argument of :not() must be a simple selector, see [definition of :not](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation) in the CSS3 spec. The code works (on sufficiently modern browsers) if you use e.g. just .newcontent as the argument.

I can’t quite see why you would also have #ipadmenu there, as you cannot validly have two elements with the same id, i.e. #ipadmenu matches as most one element in a document.

Comment: there is a sliding mechanism. During the slide, 2 elements exist, after 400ms the first one gets erased. :)